# Strike through plain text with unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, strikethrough

Is it possible to strike through <strike>unwanted</strike> revised words in your code comments? Since developers still code in <strike>the dark ages</strike> a simpler time of plain text where text cannot be formatted using hidden identifiers, the only way to accomplish this is with Unicode Characters.

Since some unicode characters can extend be̜̤͉̘̝̙͂̓ͫ̽̊̀y̐ͨͧͩ̚o̥̗̞̬̯͚͂n͔͖̤̜̖̪͒̈́ͅd̯̮ͭ their designated boundaries, I thought it might be possible to find a Unicode Character that creates the strike through effect.

Unfortunately dash characters — occupy a significant amount of horizontal space. Is there an alternative character that I can use to create the <strike>strike-through</strike> effect across my text?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's U+0336, COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY. Googling `Unicode strikethough` turns up tools to apply it to your text, such as [this one](http://adamvarga.com/strike/). Whether it looks any good will depend on your font; it looks pretty terrible on my environment.

Comment: Ah, this ̶s̶e̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ . It does seem a little short compared to wide letters like M, but you seem to have answered my question. Thanks, and sorry for not properly searching Google first.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, For simple text, its okay... but when using special characters like ~!@#$%^&*(), we might end up getting an ugly text... 
~̶!̶@̶#̶$̶%̶^̶&̶*̶(̶)̶,̶ especially when using @̶@̶@̶@̶%̶%̶%̶%̶

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this function in Python 3+ to generate it on the fly:

```
def striken(text):
    return ''.join(t+chr(822) for t in text)
```

Example output

```
>>> def striken(text):
...   return ''.join(t+chr(822) for t in text)
... 
>>> striken("hello")
'h̶e̶l̶l̶o̶
>>> striken("hello darkness my old friend")
'h̶e̶l̶l̶o̶ ̶d̶a̶r̶k̶n̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶o̶l̶d̶ ̶f̶r̶i̶e̶n̶d̶'
```

Also you may use:

```
def striken(text):
    return '\u0336'.join(text) + '\u0336'
```

to be faster if your text is really long, as suggested by @astroMonkey.

Comment: Using `'\u0336'.join(text) + '\u0336'` avoids the slower python for-loop

Comment: @astroMonkey suggestion added and off by one error fixed

Comment: @Caridorc In Unicode, diacritics are always added after the main character. So the extra strikethrough should be added to the end not the start.

Answer (score 0):

**in an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script:**

```
<^>!ü::Send {U+0336}
```

**pressing**

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> , <kbd>y</kbd> , <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> , <kbd>e</kbd> , <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> , <kbd>s</kbd>

### ̶y̶e̶s, I can strikethrough

(sorry, I chose German umlaut for shortcut, you probably want some other key)

Comment: `ü` makes perfectly sense, like "dürchgüstrüchün" or so :-)